# Electromagnetic energy in Lovelock gravities

Tags: riemannian-geometry, general-relativity, gravity-theory

To fix ideas, let us recall that General Relativity describes gravitational phenomena on a 4-dimensional pseudo-Riemannian manifold $(X,g_{ab})$ with field equations that relate the energy-momentum tensor $T_{ab}\,$ of the matter distribution to the geometry of spacetime via the so called Einstein tensor:
$$ \mathrm{Ric}_{ab} - \frac{\mathrm{scal}}{2} g_{ab} \, = \, 8 \pi\,  T_{ab} \ . $$

In this setting, the presence of an electromagnetic field is mathematically encoded with a closed 2-form $F_{ab}$.

The field equations for a spacetime with no matter and an electromagnetic field $F_{ab}$ read as follows:
$$ \mathrm{Ric}_{ab} - \frac{\mathrm{scal}}{2} g_{ab} \, = \, 8 \pi \left( F_{a \alpha}F^{\alpha}_{\ \, b} - \frac{1}{4} F^{\alpha_1 \alpha_2} F_{\alpha_1\alpha_2} g_{ab} \right) \ . $$

In other words, the energy-momentum contribution of the electromagnetic field is measured  by this tensor (sometimes called the Maxwell tensor of $F_{ab}$):
$$ \mathsf{M}_{ab} := \, F_{a\alpha}F^{\alpha}_{\ \, b} - \frac{1}{4} F^{\alpha_1\alpha_2} F_{\alpha_1\alpha_2} g_{ab} \ .  $$

My question is:

> Is there an analogue of this Maxwell tensor $\mathsf{M}_{ab}\,$ on Lovelock gravities?

---

To be more precise, Lovelock gravities are higher dimensional analogues of General Relativity, where the vacuum field equations of these theories are now defined to be:
$$ \mathrm{Ric}^{(2q)}_{ab} - \frac{\mathrm{scal}^{(2q)}}{2} g_{ab}\, = \, 0 \ , $$ where 
$$  \mathrm{Ric}^{(2q)}_{ab} := \, \delta_{a \beta_2 \dots \beta_{2q}}^{\alpha_1 \alpha_2 \dots \alpha_{2q}} R_{\alpha_1 \alpha_2 b}^{\beta_2} R_{\alpha_3 \alpha_4}^{\beta_3 \beta_4} \dots R_{\alpha_{2q-1} \alpha_{2q}}^{\beta_{2q-1 2q}} \ , $$
$$ \mathrm{scal}^{(2q)} := \, g^{\alpha \beta} \mathrm{Ric}^{(2q)}_{\alpha \beta} \qquad , \qquad \delta^{\alpha_1 \dots \alpha_{2q}}_{\beta_1 \dots \beta_{2q}} = \mathrm{det} (\delta^{\alpha_i}_{\beta_j}) \ ,  $$ and
$q$ may run from 0 to the integer part of $(\dim X - 1) /2$ (the case $q=0$ is trivial, and the case $q=1$ recovers Einstein's equation).

My question is then:

> Are there tensors $\widetilde{\mathsf{M}}^{(2q)}_{ab}\,$ that can be coupled into Lovelock equations, so that they define a reasonable theory of electromagnetism?

Of course, these tensors $\widetilde{\mathsf{M}}^{(2q)}_{ab}\,$ should be defined using $g_{ab}$ and $F_{ab}$, and the vacuum field equations
$$ \mathrm{Ric}^{(2q)}_{ab} - \frac{\mathrm{scal}^{(2q)}}{2} g_{ab}\, = \, \widetilde{\mathsf{M}}_{ab}^{(2q)} \  $$ should impose restrictions on their divergence, etc.

Comment: You say you want to consider the vacuum field equations, but then you immediately start talking about electromagnetic fields, which have a nonvanishing stress-energy.

Comment: Well, you're right, that's perhaps confusing; I meant with no contribution from matter. «In presence only of electromagnetic field» would be better... I edit that now.

Answer (score 5):

The coupling of electromagnetism (including Born-Infeld nonlinearities) to Lovelock gravity has been studied in [Magnetic Branes in Third Order Lovelock-Born-Infeld Gravity](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.1429). The nonlinearities in the Maxwell Lagrangian are introduced to obtain a finite value for the self-energy of a pointlike charge. Earlier works (cited in that reference) have worked out the linear limit.

Comment: Thanks @Carlo. I am not able to understand the BI theory, but the other references they mention —such as Wiltshire's "Black holes..." or previous references of the same authors of your cite— use, to my surprise, the Maxwell tensor (the same as in GR!) to measure the energy of the electromagnetic field in a Lovelock theory. I think  that procedure makes no sense, and that's the main reason for my question...